# Velocity squared confusion

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, speed

As far as I know, a vector cannot be squared. Velocity is also a vector, though we have equation of motion, $v^2=u^2+2aS$. I am perplexed with $v^2$ here. What does it imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector *can* be squared, viz. $v^2=v\cdot v$. The $3$-dimensional constant-acceleration equations $v-u=ta,\,v+u=2t^{-1}s$ have dot product $v^2-u^2=2a\cdot s$.

Comment: Makes sense. But dot product gives a scalar quantity. Hence is the above equation not a vector equation?

Comment: @ACB It's a "scalar equation" (in the sense both sides are scalar-valued) in which vectors appear (in that sense you might say it's also a "vector equation", but there's clearly no contradiction here).

Comment: Thanks. Furthermore is this the only scalar equation among SUVAT equations? Or others are also scalar?

Comment: @ACB The others are vector-valued: apart from $v-u=ta$, they all give a value for $s$. (We can't rearrange $v^2-u^2=2a\cdot s$ to have $s$ as its subject, except in one dimension.)

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have addressed the math part, so let's get the physics.

> I am perplexed with $v^2$ here. What does it imply ?

There's a simple physics explanation for this equation.  The expression $v^2=u^2+2aS$ can easily be arranged to get :

$$\frac 1 2 mv^2 = \frac 1 2 mu^2 + maS$$

Now $maS=FS$ is just the work done in moving that distance at that acceleration.  So this is simply an expression of energy conservation, that the change in kinetic energy is equal to the work done.

Answer (score 1):

A squared vector is defined as a dot product with itself, which corresponds to the magnitude squared of the vector: $\mathbf{ \vec v}^2=\mathbf{\vec v}\cdot \mathbf{\vec v}=\|\mathbf{\vec v}\|^2$.

So, the equation ${\bf \vec v}^2={\bf \vec u}^2+2\mathbf{\vec a}\cdot\mathbf{\vec S}$ uses the vector quantities to give you the resulting speed squared (not velocity), a scalar.

Answer (score -1):

$v$ is the speed of the object after it has decelerated with constant rate $a$ over the distance $S$ with the initial speed $u$. The object is moving in a straight line.

Comment: No, the $a$ should be a vector $\vec{a}$, as is $S$, a vector displacement $\vec{S}$=$\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_0}$. The scaler product $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{S}=|a||S|\cos\phi$. In one dimensional motion, $\phi$ is either $0$ or $\pi$. And don't assume "deceleration."

Comment: It doesn't need to be a vector. The expression can be derived from the scalar relation $v dv = a ds$. These quantities can be understood as time derivatives of a scalar coordinate. For example, if $x$ is the position of the particle along a line, then the expression is $\dot{x} d \dot{x} = \ddot{x} d x$. This comes from the chain rule.

Comment: $a$ and $S$ are not merely magnitudes, however. The direction of the acceleration relative to the displacement is critical. That means you must consider the vector ideas even if the equation, overall, seems scaler.

Comment: You don't need vectors at all. This expression comes from the chain rule of a time derivative of the positional coordinate used to *describe* the position, velocity, and acceleration vectors. But there is actually no reason to introduce them so long as the motion is rectilinear, which it is for this formula. The key misunderstanding here is that $v$ signifies a speed, not the full velocity *vector*.